# Trying to understand: clang's side-effect warnings for typeid on a polymorphic object

Tags: c++, polymorphism, clang, typeid, value-categories

This question is not about how to avoid the described warning. (Store in a reference beforehand; Or use `dynamic_cast` instead of `typeid`)

I'm trying to understand why the warning exists in the first place. What is it trying to protect from?

Consider the following code example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct A { virtual ~A() = default; };

struct B : A { };

A *get_pa() { 
    static A static_a{};
    return &static_a; 
}

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> pa1 = std::make_shared<B>();
    A *pa2 = new B{};

    //1) warning: will be evaluated
    std::cout << typeid(*pa1).name() << '\n';         

    //2) okay
    std::cout << typeid(pa1.get()).name() << '\n';  
    
    //3) okay    
    std::cout << typeid(*pa2).name() << '\n';               

    //4) warning: will be evaluated
    std::cout << typeid(*new A{}).name() << '\n';
    
    //5) warning: will not be evaluated
    std::cout << typeid(new A{}).name() << '\n'; 

    //6) warning: will be evaluated
    std::cout << typeid(*get_pa()).name() << '\n';  

    //EDIT 1:
    //7) okay
    std::cout << typeid(get_pa()).name() << '\n';
}
```

Compile this code with clang and you'll get the following kind of warning:

```
warning: expression with side effects will be evaluated despite being used as an operand to 'typeid' [-Wpotentially-evaluated-expression]
    std::cout << typeid(*pa1).name() << '\n';
                        ^
```

I think I understand the general premise of that warning:

- `typeid` will actually evaluate the expression these cases, and we might not be aware of that.
- The expression involves a polymorphic reference. Even if its class doesn't cause any side-effects, classes that inherit from it might have side-effects.
- The expression `*pa1`, is equivalent to `*pa1.get()` which calls a function returning a pointer. We might not notice/consider the fact that the dereferencing is overloaded (We might've thought it was a raw pointer, or maybe the code originally used a raw pointer and was later changed to use a smart pointer)

All of the warned expressions take a pointer to A* and dereference it (except for example 5). How can dereferencing a pointer cause a side-effect? And why don't we get a warning for the expressions that don't dereference?

<s>**EDIT 2:**
Could you give an example of a class inheriting from A that would cause a side effect where it gives a warning it might happen, but not cause a side effect where it doesn't give such a warning?</s>
**EDIT:**
Considering the answers & comments, the question in EDIT 2 is very likely a red herring, and the answer most likely involves value category rules and `typeid` rules, rather than directly involving polymorphism and its potential for overrides.

**EDIT 3:**
**Observations:**

1. As examples 6 & 7 show. The compiler doesn't really care about the expression returning a pointer to a polymorphic object having a potential side effect, but rather, it cares about the dereferencing of it having a side effect.
2. Whether we dereference a pointer or a smart pointer doesn't seem to matter, so it doesn't seem to be about overriding the dereferencing operation.
3. If we make `A` non-polymorphic (remove the virtual destructor definition) it would not show the warning for evaluating with a potential side effect (it still shows the opposite warning for example 4,5) further emphasizing that the problem is not with an expression returning a pointer but with the dereferencing them.
4. and yet, example 3 seems to contradict the other observations, since if the problem was with dereferencing it, it shouldn't matter whether the pointer itself has a name or not.
5. Thus far any explanation of what we are being warned for, as well as when the compiler looks ahead to consider a warning and when it doesn't seems to be inconsistent.

Comment: You are certainly right, people mostly think `typeid` does not evaluate the expression like `decltype` and `sizeof`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494928/clang-warning-on-expression-side-effects

Comment: Offtopic: using godbot as a demo is a good practice: https://godbolt.org/z/T8Txr8cKG

Comment: @273K Yes, I've seen that question. It also made me consider whether this question would be a duplicate. But the linked question seems to be more focused/satisfied on how to avoid the warning rather than on why it happens. (one of the comments seems to answer it but I think having it further explained and appear as its own answer could be beneficial)

Comment: @MarekR Definitely. I've used godbolt to check my examples. Although, at least for this particualr case, any good editor/IDE with clangd's language server should also be beneficial (since we care less about the assembly analysis in this case, though we might care  about how different compilers/version would work). Also, the leak sanitizer and markings in your linked code are a nice touch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already explain the purpose of the warning correctly, so I will just go through the list to explain why it does or does not apply in each case:

```
//1) warning: will be evaluated
std::cout << typeid(*pa1).name() << '\n';
```

`pa1` is not a pointer, it is a class type, a `std::shared_ptr<A>`. It is true that the dereferencing still doesn't have any side effect, but to determine that for sure the compiler would need to figure out what the overloaded `operator*` exactly does. Compiler's don't usually do such deeper analysis for warnings. That it still warns although it can't prove whether side effects are possible either way is a choice made by the compiler developers.

```
//2) okay
std::cout << typeid(pa1.get()).name() << '\n';
```

This one is okay because `pa1.get()` is a pointer type. It is not a polymorphic glvalue and therefore the expression will not be evaluated at all. `typeid` only evaluates the operand if it is a polymorphic glvalue, which is part of why one can easily get confused whether the operand will cause side effects. `typeid(pa1.get())` is always `A*`, determined at compile-time.

```
//3) okay    
std::cout << typeid(*pa2).name() << '\n';
```

This one is okay because you are really only dereferencing a pointer which, without having to look through other functions, is guaranteed not to have side effects.

```
//4) warning: will be evaluated
std::cout << typeid(*new A{}).name() << '\n';
```

This has a side effect because it allocates memory. The warning here is really useful, because `*new A{}` is going to lead to a guaranteed memory leak, so the side effect is definitively unintended.

```
//5) warning: will not be evaluated
std::cout << typeid(new A{}).name() << '\n';
```

As above `new A{}` evaluates to a pointer prvalue, not a polymorphic glvalue, so the expression won't be evaluated. But `new A{}` has a guaranteed side effect, so why would you have written it if you don't intent the side effect? Just `A*` would be fine and less prone to mistake.

```
//6) warning: will be evaluated
std::cout << typeid(*get_pa()).name() << '\n';
```

Again, the compiler is not likely to look through the `get_pa` call to determine whether it has side effects. In this case `get_pa` does have a side effect. It initializes the `static` variable. So in any case the warning is warranted.

---

In any case, the warnings can be avoided and the intention be made clearer by simply not passing anything but an id-expression to `typeid`. For example you can state clearly that evaluation will happen like this:

```
auto& obj = *get_pa();
std::cout << typeid(obj).name() << '\n';
```

Comment: I've considered similar reasonings as you did regarding the examples, but I still found them lacking: Problem 1) The weakness of that reasoning is shown with exmaple 6 and its counter-example (see newly added edit 1, example 7). if the compiler really cared for the potential side-effect it would've warned about ```get_pa()``` and not just about ```*get_pa()```. Additionally, if you make ```A``` non-polymorphic you get no warning despite the local-static, this to me implies that the warning focuses on the dereferencing aspect not the pointer.  ...(no room in the comment)

Comment: @ShmuelValariola As I mentioned in my answer, if the expression is not a _polymorphic glvalue_, then `typeid` will not evaluate it at all. `get_pa()` is a _prvalue_ expression, not a _glvalue_, and its type is `A*` which is not a polymorphic type (only class types can be polymorphic, a pointer can't). Since the expression is not evaluated, it makes no sense to warn about _potential_ side effects. Instead it makes sense to warn that side effects _won't_ happen (as the developer might expect them). `typeid` has two completely different behaviors for these two categories of expressions.

Comment: @ShmuelValariola The only difference here is that the compiler authors decided to warn in the polymorphic glvalue case about the evaluation if it is unknown whether the expression may have a side effect, while they decided to only warn about the non-evaluation if it is known that the expression has a side effect. An in either case "known" probably does generally include looking through function calls.

Comment: So, If I understand correctly: (i) We know ```typeid``` evaluates the expression only if it's ```glvalue``` to a polymorphic; (ii) A function call returning a pointer is a ```prvalue``` , also, a pointer of a polymorphic is not itself polymorphic, so either way, this doesn't evaluate, so no warning; (iii) Dereferencing such a call is an ```lvalue``` (thus, a ```glvalue```) so it evaluates, so we do get a warning; (iv) these warnings for potenital side-effect consider what could potentially happen, while warning for lack of side-effect consider what is known to (otherwise) happen.

Comment: The points shown in this discussion seems to be the more direct answer, or at least the one I'm looking for. Think you could add them to your answer?